# Receiving "RuntimeError: Session is closed" in aiohttp.ClientSession.get(), even after creating new context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am writing a web crawler using aiohttp, and my program is crashing with `"RuntimeError: Session is closed"` errors in my web crawler.

The main loop makes it through the first iteration, fetching and processing all pages in the URL queue without any issue. But then as it enters `fetch_pages()` in the 2nd iteration of the main loop, and makes first call to `aiohttp.ClientSession.session.get()`, it throws `"RuntimeError: Session is closed"`.

I don't understand why I would be getting this error, because it appears to me that the code below should be creating a new `aiohttp.ClientSession()` context manager each time the `get_batch()` function below is called, and closing the session at the end of the function call. But this is not happening. Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error?

I have posted the relevant portions of my code below (I tried to trim as much as possible, but have included links to full source below).

---

Here is the main loop:

```
class Crawler():

    ((...))

    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.url_queue = URLQueue(maxsize=10000)        # urls are popped from URL queue
        self.page_queue = asyncio.PriorityQueue()       # when fetched, they are placed on page queue for html processing  

    ((...))

    async def fetch_pages(self):
        print("Entering fetch_page()")
        pages, errors = [], []
        if self.url_queue.empty():    
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

        else:
            await self.fetcher.get_batch(self.BATCH_SIZE, self.url_queue, self.page_queue, self.error_queue)

    ((...))

    async def process_html(self): ...
    async def analyze_content(self): ...
    async def extract_links(self): ...
    async def index_content(self): ...
    async def handle_errors(self): ...

    ((...))

    async def main(self):

        try:
            while True:
                tasks = [t.loop.create_task(t.fetch_pages()),
                        t.loop.create_task(t.process_html()),
                        t.loop.create_task(t.analyze_content()),
                        t.loop.create_task(t.index_content()),
                        t.loop.create_task(t.handle_errors())]

                await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("shutting down")

        finally:
            print("Pretending to save the URL queue, etc ... ")   

    t = Crawler()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        #asyncio.run(crawler.crawl(index), debug=True)
        t.loop.run_until_complete(t.main())
```

(*full code [here](http://dpaste.com/1WF7R4K)*) ...

and here is the code for the fetch loop:

```
class Fetcher():

    ((...))

    def __init__(self, domain_manager=None, http_headers = None, dns_cache_lifetime = 300, request_timeout = 30, 
                 connection_timeout = 5, max_connections = 20, max_connections_per_host = 5, obey_robots = False,
                 verify_ssl_certs = False):

        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        self.domain_manager = domain_manager    # rate limit requests / robots.txt on per-domain basis

        self.timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=request_timeout, 
                                             connect=connection_timeout)  

        self.connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ttl_dns_cache=dns_cache_lifetime, 
                                              limit=max_connections, 
                                              limit_per_host=max_connections_per_host,
                                              ssl=verify_ssl_certs)


    async def fetch(self, url, session):
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:                
                status = int(resp.status)
                headers = dict(resp.headers)        

                if self.check_response_headers(url, status, headers):

                    html = await resp.text()

                    return {'url': url,
                            'headers': headers,
                            'html': html,
                            'last_visit': datetime.now()}
                else:
                    raise FetchError(f"Fetch failed for url {url}: Header check failed (but why did we make it here?)", 
                                     url=url, exception=e, fetch_stage="GET")

        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
       ((...))


    def check_response_headers(self, url, status, headers):
        """Given a response from fetch(), return a (Page object, error object) pair"""

       ((...))


    async def fetch_with_dm(self, url, session, i):
        """fetches next url from queue until successfully fetches a page"""

        domain = self.domain_manager.domain_from_url(url)

        ((...))

        async with self.domain_manager.locks[domain]:

            ((...))

            fetch_result = await self.fetch(url, session)

            return fetch_result


    async def get_batch(self, batch_size, url_queue, page_queue, error_queue):
        start_time = datetime.now()

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=self.timeout, connector=self.connector) as session:
            tasks = []
            for i in range(batch_size):
                url = None          
                score = None

                if url_queue.empty():
                    break

                else:
                    score, url = url_queue.get_nowait()  # should we be blocking here / await / sleeping if no urls in queue?

                    if url == None:
                        raise ValueError("Received empty URL")

                    if score == None:
                        raise ValueError("Received empty URL score")

                    tasks.append(self.loop.create_task(self.fetch_with_dm(url, session, i)))


            for p in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
                try:
                    page = await p
                    page['url_score'] = score
                    await page_queue.put((score, id(page), page))

                except FetchError as fe:
                    await error_queue.put(fe)
```

(*full code [here](http://dpaste.com/3ZXBJQH)*)

... Again the "session closed" error is occuring when `session.get(url)` is called in `fetch`, but only in the second iteration of main loop ...

Comment: This error means that some of the coroutines that reference session have continued running in the "background" after the `async with` has closed the session. `run_until_complete` runs until the given awaitable completes; it doesn't ensure that tasks spawned by that awaitable complete as well. As a consequence, the _next_ `run_until_complete` continues running the "old" tasks as well as the new ones. In your code I don't see off-hand how the tasks would survive the `async with` (which is why this is a comment and not an answer), but that's how I would approach debugging it.